# Weka - Is there a good way to handle (a lot of) numeric attributes for classifying a nominal value?

Tags: weka

Best

I've a lot of numeric values and at the end, I want to predict a result.
My result can have the nominal values of '0','1' or 'x'.

What I like to know is, how can I get the best results.
Can some classifiers handle numeric attributes better than another? 
And sometimes it seems that a classifier has a focus on a less interesting attribute...

Also at the moment h. means home team and a. means away team. Would it be better if I split this and add an attribute, location @location {'h', 'a'} --> 0 will become 1 and vica versa

```
@relation estimation
@attribute h.teamSize numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamFormation {'5-2-0-3-1' ... '6-2-0-4-1'}
@attribute h.teamRatingAVG numeric
@attribute h.teamRatingHighest numeric
@attribute h.teamRatingLowest numeric
@attribute h.teamRatingMed numeric
@attribute h.teamRatingMedRating numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRating.att numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRating.attMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRating.mid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRating.defMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRating.def numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.att numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.attMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.mid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.defMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.def numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.att numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.attMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.mid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.defMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.def numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.att numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.attMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.mid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.defMid numeric
@attribute h.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.def numeric
@attribute a.teamSize numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamFormation {'5-2-0-3-1' ... '6-2-0-4-1'}
@attribute a.teamRatingAVG numeric
@attribute a.teamRatingHighest numeric
@attribute a.teamRatingLowest numeric
@attribute a.teamRatingMed numeric
@attribute a.teamRatingMedRating numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRating.att numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRating.attMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRating.mid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRating.defMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRating.def numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.att numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.attMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.mid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.defMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingAVG.def numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.att numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.attMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.mid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.defMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingHighest.def numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.att numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.attMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.mid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.defMid numeric
@attribute a.lineUpTeamRatingLowest.def numeric
@attribute result {'0','1','x'}
@data
11.0,"4-1-1-4-1",1563.0046902930617,1716.018383910481,1493.642106150469,1542.5395864396032,1604.830245030475,1594.8952627985404,6230.782838756112,1552.485746007047,1716.018383910481,6098.869361751494,1594.8952627985404,1557.695709689028,1552.485746007047,1716.018383910481,1524.7173404378734,1594.8952627985404,1617.8284702417561,1552.485746007047,1716.018383910481,1542.4611979096933,1594.8952627985404,1493.642106150469,1552.485746007047,1716.018383910481,1510.4250125761928,11.0,"5-1-1-2-2",1588.961662996073,1747.6289170494754,1508.4062919834894,1565.5233012334515,1628.0176045164824,3459.80148294728,3079.552081457912,1542.4682316024448,1576.1754548839763,7820.5810420651915,1729.90074147364,1539.776040728956,1542.4682316024448,1576.1754548839763,1564.1162084130383,1747.6289170494754,1549.4953619285486,1542.4682316024448,1576.1754548839763,1613.8600439857894,1712.1725658978046,1530.0567195293636,1542.4682316024448,1576.1754548839763,1508.4062919834894,"x"
11.0,"4-2-2-2-1",1475.8094913912312,1502.0682887709222,1444.990021885439,1483.7603435487183,1473.5291553281807,1490.639636207262,2978.5093856157946,2950.4346148352724,2892.2037554297044,5922.117013215507,1490.639636207262,1489.2546928078973,1475.2173074176362,1446.1018777148522,1480.5292533038767,1490.639636207262,1492.9037337533382,1502.0682887709222,1447.2137335442653,1496.2886114276891,1490.639636207262,1485.6056518624566,1448.3663260643502,1444.990021885439,1460.927921231502,11.0,"4-1-2-2-2",1484.7390000692892,1512.2300048742143,1453.444107111614,1486.4669707831615,1482.837055992914,3013.771836727523,2964.5776806684476,2961.501146916992,1453.444107111614,5938.834229337606,1506.8859183637614,1482.2888403342238,1480.750573458496,1453.444107111614,1484.7085573344016,1512.2300048742143,1501.9409533482967,1493.2838448180084,1453.444107111614,1502.7776443004382,1501.5418318533088,1462.6367273201508,1468.2173020989835,1453.444107111614,1464.7837448131381,"1"
11.0,"6-0-1-2-2",1445.77970697302,1506.5657818615387,1393.7116666209088,1430.4622334716257,1450.1387242412238,2937.7942649521,3010.9183806060323,1402.8170557672368,0.0,8552.047075377852,1468.89713247605,1505.4591903030162,1402.8170557672368,NaN,1425.341179229642,1483.5459383871223,1506.5657818615387,1402.8170557672368,-1.0,1465.0738948215799,1454.248326564978,1504.3525987444937,1402.8170557672368,2.147483647E9,1393.7116666209088,11.0,"4-2-2-2-1",1430.4629022453128,1474.4893525633652,1404.2919287564614,1426.6619540429597,1439.3906406599133,1404.2919287564614,2864.6817220202643,2906.4018234232753,2831.550186683904,5728.166263814535,1404.2919287564614,1432.3408610101321,1453.2009117116377,1415.775093341952,1432.0415659536338,1404.2919287564614,1452.1579439472125,1474.4893525633652,1426.6619540429597,1458.4115214984754,1404.2919287564614,1412.5237780730517,1431.9124708599102,1404.8882326409444,1413.8219682802633,"x"
11.0,"6-1-1-2-1",1455.2875865157116,1533.8148260877508,1408.8080092768812,1454.6219157957269,1471.311417682316,1440.5588774260157,2975.472084744947,1454.6219157957269,1489.241573073469,8648.269000632668,1440.5588774260157,1487.7360423724735,1454.6219157957269,1489.241573073469,1441.3781667721114,1440.5588774260157,1533.8148260877508,1454.6219157957269,1489.241573073469,1475.4245410744663,1440.5588774260157,1441.6572586571963,1454.6219157957269,1489.241573073469,1408.8080092768812,11.0,"7-1-1-1-1",1478.6812699237746,1573.5345947486803,1376.2807543215677,1487.4841795952277,1474.907674535124,1573.5345947486803,1438.3659332206364,1510.946520366525,1376.2807543215677,10366.36616650411,1573.5345947486803,1438.3659332206364,1510.946520366525,1376.2807543215677,1480.90945235773,1573.5345947486803,1438.3659332206364,1510.946520366525,1376.2807543215677,1501.6224047599273,1573.5345947486803,1438.3659332206364,1510.946520366525,1376.2807543215677,1421.1718685458247,"0"
...
```

I hope that someone with experience can give me some advice.
Thus:

- A good way to deal with numeric data
- A good way to deal with lots of attributes

[I know that there isn't such a thing as the best way but I'm already happy with a good way :)

Kind regards

Comment: There may be a classifier for your task, but there is no "best" classifier for everything, it really depends on the data and the type of data. You'll probably have to try out some classifiers, but I'd give SVMs a shot. Regarding the 'h' and 'a', I don't think you can split it.

Answer (score 0):

Trial and Error may be the best way to determine the classifier that is 'best'.  It really comes down to a number of factors, such as the layout and preprocessing of the data, the amount of data, and the fit of the problem to the classifier.

At a quick glance, you might be able to try J48, Neural Networks or SVMs.  The only part that might need changing is the Formation attributes (split them into 5 attributes perhaps?).  Besides this, a lot of classifiers would then be able to predict the nominal output based on the numeric information supplied.

As for the home vs away part, it looks good as it stands, and would likely be better to leave out the extra attribute.  These types of problems typically favour the home team, but you appear to already know who is home and who is away, so it shouldn't really add much to the model.

Have a play with what's available and see how you go.  The results may surprise you!